# Why is Dulles Airport (KIAD) not in any chart supplement?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, chart-supplement

I was recently listening to the KIAD ground feed, and realized that I had no diagram. When I tried to find one in the northeast chart supplement (which does have the information section), I couldn't. Is this because of the special flight rules around DC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s in there.  Look under Washington, District of Columbia.

[image]
[image]

Comment: As an adjunct to this, does anyone know why KIAD and KDCA are listed under "District of Columbia" instead of Virginia, where they actually are? KCVG is correctly under "Covington, Kentucky"